# Como incrementar um objeto de estado com outro objeto em React Native?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Basicamente eu tenho esse método que pega algumas informações da API e guarda em uma variável do estado (data: []), mas como são várias páginas, eu gostaria de ir acrescentando os resultados nessa variável para apresentar, depois de todas as requisições, todos resultados, mas não sei como faço isso.

```
makeRemoteRequest = (page) =>{
 const url = `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=<<api_key>>&page=${page}`;
  this.setState({loading: true});

  fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                data:res.results,
                error: res.error || null,
                loading: false,
            })
            this.arrayholder = res.results;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            this.setState({error, loading:false});
        })        
    }
```

O `state`:

```
state = {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    error: null,
    page: 1,
}
```

Já tentei usar uma outra variável para controlar, mas eu preciso de um objeto, pois para mostrar os resultados finais precisarei de todos os dados do resultado da API.

Comment: quantas páginas tem esse requisição? isso não é muito legal em fazer se o número de paginas for grande.

Comment: 500 pages. Mas eu não pretendo pegar todas. Apenas 2 ou 3.

Comment: então pode ser feito um for somente, mas, a sua duvida é como agregar os resultados, como juntar os resultados (é uma lista de valores neh, ou seja um array)

Comment: Isso. Tecnicamente eu já consegui fazer isso, mas quando eu passo para arrays, eu consigo pegar apenas o title (response.data.title) e converter para uma string que vai ficar na array. Mas eu também precisaria pegar outros valores, como response.data.id, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo no seu caso, pode usar a desestruturação que veio com o ES6 no JavaScript, da seguinte forma:

```
state = {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
    error: null,
    page: 1,
}

makeRemoteRequest = (page) =>{
 const url = `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=<<api_key>>&page=${page}`;
  this.setState({loading: true});

  fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                data:[...data, ...res.results],
                error: res.error || null,
                loading: false,
            })
            this.arrayholder = res.results;
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            this.setState({error, loading:false});
        })        
    }
```

Assim você continua com os dados que havia no array de data e insere novos dados pela resposta da api.

Answer (score 0):

Para reunir informações entre dois ou mais `array` em `javascript` pode usar a técnica de ***desestruturação*** ([que possibilita extrair dados de arrays ou objetos em variáveis distintas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao)), exemplo:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [4, 5, 6, 7];
const c = [ ... a, ... b];

console.log(c);
```

Também pode utilizar o método `.concat` para concatenar dois `arrays`:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [4, 5, 6, 7];
const c = a.concat(b);

console.log(c);
```